# Calling API service and setting recyclerView adapter from in Firebase onDataChange?

Tags: android, api, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm new to java android and completely stuck on this problem.

**The following is working:**

1. User logs in, App generates 30 random photos from UnSpash.com through their API. Photos are placed on screen by RecyclerView. My `getFoodPictures()`
2. Logged in users of app can edit a picture with a description. This
       is saved to Firebase (User, Picture ID, & description).
3. App retrieves a user's Described photos from Firebase when they log in and
   stores in array. my `getUserFood()` method using Firebase `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`

**Not Working:**

When user logs in, I want RecyclerView as it binds each photo to view, to compare each API generated photo with User's array of Described Photos(that I got from Firebase).  And if API photo is in the User's array of Described photos, then bind the view with the User's Described photo instead of API one.

**The problem, as I understand it, is async**

From research on here, Firebase `addListenerForSingleValueEvent' is async. So I end up getting the Users Photo descriptions from Firebase **AFTER** the API call and RecyclerView do their job.

Many posts here recommended thinking about working with Firebase onDataChange with a mindset of:

"When data is returned, then do something with data".

**Moved API+RecyclerView method into FireBase call for user data**

So I moved my API+RecyclerView method `getFoodPictures()` into the Firebase method to get User data. `getFoodPictures()` is called from inside onDataChange.

**Images appear for a moment and then disappear**

Doing this has resolved my async issue. User data from Firebase is returned before RecyclerView starts binding views.

But, as RecyclerView goes into action and binds the views, the images appear for a flickr and then are gone. App doesn't crash, I can still log out and log in from the menu. There just isn't any list to scroll through.

**What would be helpful to me**

1. Before I moved my API call into the Firebase method, I tried to
   figure out how to save the User data returned from Firebase
   **BEFORE** API call and recycler view started.

   I didn't get it.  Some posts mentioned Interfaces and I'm too new to
   understand the examples they provided.

   If you have a clear example of how to get and set Firebase data **BEFORE** my
   API+recycler view do their job, please share.
2. Assuming I am on a right track by placing `getFoodPictures()`
   inside the Firebase onDataChange,  how do I get the images
   and recyclerView to not disappear?

My UnSpash Service seting up the API call

```
public class UnSplashService {
    public static void getPictures(Callback callback){
        HttpUrl.Builder urlBuilder = HttpUrl.parse(Constants.UNSPLASH_URL).newBuilder();
        urlBuilder.addQueryParameter(Constants.UNSPLASH_CLIENT_ID, Constants.UNSPLASH_ID);
        String url = urlBuilder.build().toString();
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .build();
        Request request= new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();
        Call call = client.newCall(request);
        call.enqueue(callback);
    }
...
```

My getFoodPictures method on Main Activity. `getPictures` from UnSplash service goes into setting recyclerView on a `Runnable` callback on `runOnUiThread`

```
public void getFoodPictures(){
        mOpenDescribe = this;
        final UnSplashService unSplashService = new UnSplashService();
        unSplashService.getPictures(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
                     mPictures = unSplashService.processResults(response);
                     MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                          mAdapter = new PictureListAdapter(mOpenDescribe, getApplicationContext
                                  (), mPictures, userFoods);
                            AlphaInAnimationAdapter animateAdapter = new AlphaInAnimationAdapter(mAdapter);
                            animateAdapter.setDuration(1500);
                            mPictureRecycleView.setAdapter(new AlphaInAnimationAdapter(animateAdapter));
                            mPictureRecycleView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
    }
```

My `getUserFood` Firebase method. On Main activity.

```
public void getUserFoods(){
        final ArrayList<Picture> tempUserFoods = new ArrayList<>();
        String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.FIREBASE_CHILD_DESCRIBED_FOODS).child(uid);
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.d("Snapshot", dataSnapshot.toString());
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    tempUserFoods.add(snapshot.getValue(Picture.class));
                }
                userFoods = tempUserFoods;
                getFoodPictures();
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
```

onCreate in Main, I call `createAuthStateListener();` to check for user login. 
Here, `getUserFoods()` is called.

```
public void createAuthStateListener(){
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                final FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null){
                    getUserFoods();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(user.getDisplayName()+", you hungry?");
                } else {
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
                }
                mAdapter.showHideFoodListener();
            }
        };
    }
```

Here is my adapter for RecyclerView

```
public class PictureListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PictureListAdapter.PictureViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Picture> mPictures = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context mContext;
    private OpenDescribeFragment mOpenDescribe;
    public FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    public ArrayList<Picture> mUserFoods;

    public PictureListAdapter() { }

    public PictureListAdapter (OpenDescribeFragment listener, Context context, ArrayList<Picture>
            pictures, ArrayList<Picture> userFoods){
        super ();
        mOpenDescribe = listener;
        mContext = context;
        mPictures = pictures;
        mUserFoods = userFoods;
    }

    public class PictureViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        @Bind(R.id.pictureItemView)
        ImageView mPictureView;
        @Bind(R.id.findFoodButton)
        ImageButton mFindFoodButton;
        @Bind(R.id.descriptionTextView)
        TextView descriptionTextView;
        private Context context;

        public PictureViewHolder(View itemView)   {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
            mContext = itemView.getContext();
            mFindFoodButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        }

        public void bindPicture(Picture picture) {
            Picasso.with(mContext).load(picture.getImageUrl()).into(mPictureView);
            if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){
                mFindFoodButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                mFindFoodButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(v == mFindFoodButton) {
                mOpenDescribe.openDescribeFragment(v, mPictures.get(getAdapterPosition()));
            }
        }

    }
    @Override
    public PictureViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.picture_list_item, parent, false);
        PictureViewHolder viewHolder = new PictureViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PictureViewHolder holder,  int position) {
        holder.bindPicture(mPictures.get(position));
        Log.d("Size of User Foods", Integer.toString(mUserFoods.size()));

    }

    public void showHideFoodListener() {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mPictures.size();
    }
}
```